# Indexing issue in Nutch-Solr (Want to display data in solr)

Tags: solr, lucene, nutch

I am trying to **crawl data** using **Nutch** and **Index** that Data in **Solr**.

I have follow the steps from this Url [Using Nutch with Solr](http://searchhub.org/2009/03/09/nutch-solr/) and [Nutch Wiki Tutorial](http://wiki.apache.org/nutch/NutchTutorial)

I've successfully Index data using **Solrindex command**

`bin/nutch solrindex http://127.0.0.1:8983/solr/ crawl/crawldb -linkdb crawl/linkdb crawl/segments/*` but in Result I can't find the Indexed data.

I want result as below Image[image: Solr Query]

But I can't see any result data at right side.

Answer (score 1):

If you want some data to be returned with the search response, check that the targeted fields are stored by solr, then you can set a list of fields to return in your query using `fl` param (with stored field name as value). You can also set default fl values in solrconfig.xml.

For example, let's say you want `content` field to be returned. In your schema.xml, in the `<fields>` declaration you should have the option `stored="true"` for this field like so :

```
<field name="content" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

Then in solrconfig.xml, declare default fl params in the requestHandler definition, you can set specific fields (space separated field names). The xml sample (grabbed from the tutorial) should look like this if we just want data stored in the `content` field to be returned.

```
<requestHandler name="/nutch" class="solr.SearchHandler" >
  <lst name="defaults">
    <str name="defType">dismax</str>
    <str name="echoParams">explicit</str>
    <float name="tie">0.01</float>
    <str name="qf">
    content^0.5 anchor^1.0 title^1.2
    </str>
    <str name="pf">
    content^0.5 anchor^1.5 title^1.2 site^1.5
    </str>
    <str name="fl">
    url content
    </str>
    <str name="mm">
    2&lt;-1 5&lt;-2 6&lt;90%
    </str>
    <int name="ps">100</int>
    <bool hl="true"/>
    <str name="q.alt">*:*</str>
    <str name="hl.fl">title url content</str>
    <str name="f.title.hl.fragsize">0</str>
    <str name="f.title.hl.alternateField">title</str>
    <str name="f.url.hl.fragsize">0</str>
    <str name="f.url.hl.alternateField">url</str>
    <str name="f.content.hl.fragmenter">regex</str>
  </lst>
</requestHandler>
```

You can override these defaults right in the query. A common use case is to put "`*,score`" in the fl area in solr query interface so that you can see all stored fields (using wildcard character `*`) along with the score in the results. You might also want to specify the query type parameter (qt) according to the targeted request handler (should be "/nutch").

Helpful links :

http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SchemaXml#Common_field_options
http://wiki.apache.org/solr/CommonQueryParameters#fl